# Почему Фёдор Достоевский, но Чарльз Буковски?

Tags: падежи, выбор-имени, заимствования

Почему мы читаем романы [Фёдора Достоевского](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%A4%D1%91%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), но читаем стихи [Чарльза Буковски](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8,_%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7)?

Comment: Потому что Достоевский русский писатель а Чарльз Буковски американец - и сам себя Буковским никогда не называл.

Comment: Кроме всего перечисленного следует добавить, что аналогичная фамилия женщины может быть на -ки (Кински и т.п.).

Answer (score 10):

Транскрипция только **польских** фамилий даёт в русском варианте "-ий", и если это делается *через английский* язык, то в случаях, когда польское происхождение носителя фамилии хорошо известно, например Збигнев Бжезинский.

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Польско-русская_практическая_транскрипция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

В нашем же случае автор (по википедии) - *немецкого* происхождения.

Answer (score 8):

Потому что Буковски - это иностранная фамилия, и ее склонять по русским правилам не принято. Нет русских фамилий на -и, которые бы склонялись в единственном числе.

А Достоевский - русский писатель с русской фамилией, которую мы склоняем.

Как Дарвин - с Дарвином, но Ленин - с Лениным. Разные правила для иностранных и русских фамилий.

Answer (score 8):

Общая установка на то, что иностранные фамилии остаются иностранными, даже когда они морфологически прозрачны в силу происхождения из родственных славянских языков (или даже русского). Бывала и противоположная традиция, когда не имеющий никакой славянской этимологии* силач Eugene Sandow дотягивался до «Евгения Сандова», но мы живем при устоявшихся в советское время академических нормах, и если они и меняются, то в сторону еще большей «неприкосновенности» иностранных фамилий.

---

*или, возможно, отдаленную западнославянскую через немецкий топоним Sandau, но вряд ли дореволюционные «локализаторы» заходили так глубоко.